# Library push message Laravel FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) Notification Channel

Tags: laravel, firebase-cloud-messaging

Help how to interact with Laravel FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) Notification Channel library, I'm trying to send a message at least to myself, but nothing happens, and in the documentation for it nothing is normally described.

```
 public function via($notifiable)
{
    return [FcmChannel::class];
}

public function toFcm($notifiable)
{

    return FcmMessage::create()
        ->setData(['dDH_PSJGR-iIwpLOgsWufE:APA91bH_V_gPwjEcWGxmMbl00Z33eSFV3Zpzc6Sjqb3UlxIwJUtrjlYnBPAvXhx6D6CPMVe9em5UFXZ9kzZlHQrirF0loBdHchBEjVpY_JRi-RNVUQAw3Rok50nayxZLV_uAlHbHzAfG'])
        ->setNotification(\NotificationChannels\Fcm\Resources\Notification::create()
            ->setTitle('Account Activated')
            ->setBody('Your account has been activated.'))
            ->setToken('dDH_PSJGR-iIwpLOgsWufE:APA91bH_V_gPwjEcWGxmMbl00Z33eSFV3Zpzc6Sjqb3UlxIwJUtrjlYnBPAvXhx6D6CPMVe9em5UFXZ9kzZlHQrirF0loBdHchBEjVpY_JRi-RNVUQAw3Rok50nayxZLV_uAlHbHzAfG');
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)